# Are there any Google services that allow saving user data to the cloud to be shared with other users?

Tags: android, google-apps, google-drive

I'm trying to figure if any existing Google services would allow users of an app I'm developing to save data to the cloud that they would be able to share with others in their organization. The data in question is basically information about customers, that might need to be accessed by multiple users in an organization at random times.

I've been looking at Google Cloud Save, but I don't see anything saying the data can be shared (and also it appears oriented toward games, which is not what I'm developing).

The type of data I'm trying to save would be databases about customers, which would contain pictures. I took a look at Google Cloud SQL, but that looks like it's saving in the developer's space instead of the user's Google Drive, which I would prefer (I would also prefer to avoid maintenance costs).

Are there any Google services that might allow me to save data per user, but allows the user to specify other users that can access the data?

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive

It has an API and you can do sharing on each file and/or folder.
Manually, you right click on anything in Google Drive and click share and tell it who you want to share to and what permissions they have and your done.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk

Click on the programming language of choice and BOOM code samples.

Google Docs could also be used.